# Is a friend function defined in-class automatically inline?

Tags: c++, inline, friend

If a member function is defined inside the class, it is an inline function. E.g.

```
struct X
{
   void mem_f() {} //mem_f is inline
};
```

My question is whether a nonmember friend function defined inside the class is also automatically inline.

E.g.

```
struct Y
{ 
   friend void friend_f() {} //is friend_f inline?
};
```

A relevant quote/paragraph_no from the standard would be much welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is. §11.4/5:

> A function can be defined in a friend
>   declaration of a class if and only if
>   the class is a non-local class (9.8),
>   the function name is unqualified, and
>   the function has namespace scope.
>   **Such a function is implicitly inline.** A friend function defined in
>   a class is in the (lexical) scope of
>   the class in which it is defined. A
>   friend function defined outside the
>   class is not (3.4.1).

Since the class definition is presumably in a header file, the function will be multiply-defined, so it needs to be `inline`.