# Nonmember friend function is always inline

Tags: c++, inline, friend

I am very new to C++, and when I am trying to learn the friend function, I saw from [friend description on Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) that:

> 2) (only allowed in non-local class definitions) Defines a non-member function, and makes it a friend of this class at the same time. Such non-member function is always **inline**.

```
class X {
  int a;
  friend void friend_set(X& p, int i) {
    p.a = i; // this is a non-member function
  }
  public:
  void member_set(int i) {
      a = i; // this is a member function
  }
};
```

Does this mean that all friend functions always have to be **inline**? In another word, must the friend functions be defined completely inside the class?

However, I also found an instance where the friend function is defined outside the class from [Cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/)

```
// friend functions
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Rectangle {
  int width, height;
  public:
    Rectangle() {}
    Rectangle (int x, int y) : width(x), height(y) {}
    int area() {return width * height;}
    friend Rectangle duplicate (const Rectangle&);
};
Rectangle duplicate (const Rectangle& param)
{
  Rectangle res;
  res.width = param.width*2;
  res.height = param.height*2;
  return res;
}
```

I am really confused by this conflict. Is my understanding of **inline** wrong?
What does it mean by "[a nonmember friend function defined inside the class is automatically inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980627/is-a-friend-function-defined-in-class-automatically-inline)"?

Comment: "defined inside the class" is the key words here. Friend functions *defined inside the class* are inline. That does not mean that *all* friend functions are inline. Your second example clearly shows a friend function defined *outside* the class. It is not inline.

Comment: You quote syntax 2 from cppreference and then you ask "Does this mean that all friend functions always have to be inline?" No: a counter-example is given in the immediately preceding syntax 1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*any* function defined inside a class (member or non-member friend) is always implicitly inline.  That's because class definitions are generally in header files, and you don't want any non-inline function definitions in a header file (having a non-inline function in a header leads to multiple definitions if the header is #included in more than one source file).

If you want a function to be non-inline, you need to define it outside of a class definition.  If its a member or friend you still need to declare it inside the class, since members and friends *must* be declared in the class.  You just don't want it defined in the class.

This all gets into the difference between a **definition** and a **declaration** in C++ -- they are two distinct things, though every definition is also implicitly a declaration, not every declaration is a definition.  As a result, when the spec says 'declaration' it often means 'declaration that is not also a definition'

Comment: That really helps. Thank you!